# Accessing VSTS Build Server Version in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Is it possible to get the VSTS build number in Azure functions? I need to display the build version on an Httptrigger endpoint.

Comment: sorry I misread the question, I thought it was the same as the other one from yesterday. It's more of a VSTS question and I don't know the answer for. I'll delete my answer so hopefully someone else more familiar with this will reply

Comment: Do you run multiple versions simultaneously or will there always be only one version running?

Comment: 1 version at a time

Comment: How about store the build number in a file of Azure Function project, then get the data from that file in the code?

Comment: That's a path I started down. The build server is creating a settings JSON file with the build version, but I could not find a way to access it. Do you know how azure functions stores its settings on release? Locally I can access local.settings.json on the server I've not been able to find the location.

Comment: How about store the build number in the code directly? Using [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to replace data in the code (e.g. #{buildNumber}# => [actually build number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"local.settings.json" file does not work due to a known issue here: [Application settings not available from local.settings.json in Azure, but available locally in Visual Studio](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1594).

To achieve the feature you want, you can add an "Azure PowerShell Script" task in your build definition to read the VSTS build number and update the Azure Webapp Appsettings via [Set-AzureRmWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-4.3.1) command. And then you can read the settings via code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VSTSBuildVersion"]
```

The PowerShell Script for your reference:

```
$app = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -Name "AzureFunctionAppName"
$appSettings = $app.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$newSettings = @{}

ForEach ($key in $appSettings)
{
    $newSettings[$key.Name] = $key.Value
}

$newSettings['VSTSBuildVersion'] = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER

Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -Name "AzureFunctionAppName" -AppSettings $newSettings
```

Comment: Thanks you. Much appreciated.