# How to override Azure functions the environment values?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-functions

We want to be able to change the environment values.

How do we implement our environment variables using visual studio team services and do a transformation at deployment time?

Comment: It's a little low on details. Generally, in Azure App Service (whether Web Apps or Functions), you use Azure App Settings to set env variables.

Comment: ARM templates and parameter files are the best way to go. You can then configure different parameter files to run against your various environments through VSTS

Comment: Do you solve this issue? What do you think of Set-AzureRMWebApp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set/update the Appsettings via Set-AzureRMWebApp powershell command during build/release.

A related thread: [Accessing VSTS Build Server Version in Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865955/accessing-vsts-build-server-version-in-azure-function)

Comment: not sure is this is the way to go or use appsettings to override ?